# ComponenetMount add fields to array React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I am trying to solve a problem, I am getting this data from an API:

```
 rows: [
      { id: 212, title: "Task 1", complete: 20 },
      { id: 5454, title: "Task 2", complete: 40 },
      { id: 39172, title: "Task 3", complete: 60 }
    ]
```

I am using componentDidMount to setState

```
this.state = { apiData: this.props.getAllData(),
             data: [] }
componentDidMount(){
   this.state.apiData.then(data => this.setState({ data: data.rows})) }
```

the data is in the state.data, is working perfectly fine. My question is how I add an index to each row in the rows data from the api, an example like this, the length of the rows is dynamic, could be 10 row or 5 row:

```
 rows: [
      { index: 0, id: 212, title: "Task 1", complete: 20 },
      { index: 1, id: 5454, title: "Task 2", complete: 40 },
      { index: 2, id: 39172, title: "Task 3", complete: 60 }
    ]
```

Can this be done in the componentDidMount()? and setState to the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use map in your state data value, and append the index value to a new property.

```
this.state.apiData.then(data => this.setState({ data: data.rows.map((row, index) => ({ index, ...row }))) }))
```

I also would recommend to do that in different lines for readability.

```
this.state.apiData.then(result => {
  const data = result.rows.map((row, index) => ({ index, ...row }))
  this.setState({ data })
})
```

Comment: Thanks Osuka42, your example is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add this before you set the state:

```js
const rows = [
  { id: 212, title: "Task 1", complete: 20 },
  { id: 5454, title: "Task 2", complete: 40 },
  { id: 39172, title: "Task 3", complete: 60 }
]; // replace by your fetched data

let x = 0;
        
for (const i in rows) {
   rows[i].index = x++;
}

console.log(rows);
```